# How to access checkbox from items inside a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need to apply a condition to each item if true it should display the checkbox in the item, if false it should hide. How to accomplish that?

here is the xaml:

```
                    <ListBox Name="lbAllInstances" Width="500" Height="400"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                        SelectionChanged="lbAllInstances_SelectionChanged">

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using BooleanToVisibilityConverter

```
<!-- In your resources section of the XAML -->
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisibleProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
    ...
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using `DataTriggers`.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyThatSetsVisibility}" Value="True">

        <Setter TargetName="NameOfCheckBoxToHideInItemTemplate" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>

    </DataTrigger>

</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```